# Kentico's Field data type Date also showing time

Tags: kentico

When creating the fields for a page type, i have a date picker. When entering data, this also includes a time picker. Is there an option to remove the time picker portion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you need to do is un-check the "Edit time" checkbox under the "Editing control settings" for the field. That will remove the time selection part of hte control.

Note that all dates selected will be for 00:00:00 AM.

Example: 2016-01-01 00:00:00 AM

[image]

Comment: Thanks Bryan, I just saw that now, and was going to update this. See, code, early morning and no coffee. Bad combo!

Cheers!

Comment: How do i then ensure the time isn't displayed on the page? I have selected the Date data type, not the Date and Time data type.

Comment: If you are talking about your transformation, you can use the built-in FormatDate transformation method.

<%# FormatDate(Eval("BlogPostDate")) %> would result in 1/22/2016

Comment: Thanks, i was going to dig into the culture settings.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Set the Data Type (the second parameter under General) to Date, instead of Date and Time.